# How to hide column in some nodes in Devexpress ASPxTreeList control?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I'm using ASPxTrrList control from Devexpress and I want to hide delete button (or any column) in some nodes depending on specific condition.
I tried (HtmlRowPrepared) event but I couldn't locate the column I want, it looks like its index changes depending on the node level.

Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using this code:

```
 protected void MyTree_HtmlCommandCellPrepared(object sender, TreeListHtmlCommandCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var node = MyTree.GetAllNodes().SingleOrDefault(k => k.Key == e.NodeKey);
        if (node != null && anyCondition)
            e.Cell.Visible = false;
    }
```

I'm using only one command button, so I didn't try to hide specific button.